# Laravel : Check the reason for failure of validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am preforming validation on a attribute with two rules: `required` and `unique`. The attribute `att1` in combination with `att2` and `att3` should be unique in database. I want to display the error message in view in different place for different reasons of failure. For example, if validation failed due to `required` rule, I want to display error message in one div and if it failed due to `unique` rule  I want to display error message in another div.

Here is my validator :

```
$messages = [
        'att1.unique' => 'Given combination has already been registered.',
        'att1.required' => 'Please select att1',
        'att2.required' => 'Please select your att2',
        'att3.required' => 'Please select your att3',
    ];
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        'att1' => [
            'bail','required',
            Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use($attr1,$attr2,$attr3) {
                return $query->where('att1', $attr1)
                ->where('att2', $attr2)
                ->where('att3', $attr2);
            }),
        ],
        'att2' => ['required'],
        'att3' => ['required'],
    ],$messages);
```

How do I display the error message for `att1.unique` and `att1.required` in different places when they occur ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do two conditional checks as follows.

```
if ($errors->has('att1')) {
    foreach ($errors->get('att1') as $error) {
        // This would list all errors for the att1 field
        // Then it's just a simple conditional statement to
        // check if it's the error you want
        if($error == 'Please select att1') {} 
    }
}
```

and repeat the  this for the unique rule. I cannot seem to find another better way of doing this.

You can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) on how to retrieve errors for a specific field.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. Just a little question: Can that for loop be avoided because `$errors -> get('att1')` always has only one value. If the value is not supplied in the input, the `required` validation fails and `unique` rule is not checked because of `bail` rule. And if `unque` validation fails, it means that input is given and `required` rule cannot fail.
I tried `if($errors->get('att1') == 'Please select att1') { $errors->first('att1') } ` but that didn't display anything.

Comment: You can use `$errors->first('att1')` in this particular case :)